# Does minimizing the windows reduce the RAM usage?

Tags: unity, ram, ram-usage

I want to know whether minimizing the windows purposefully helps in reducing the RAM usage.

Comment: It can, depends on the window. Please [edit] your question and give a specific example.

Comment: How much RAM do you have, by the way? Can you paste the typical output of 'free -h' when you have many windows open?

Comment: You can easily find out. Open many windows and run system monitor. See if it makes a difference if you minimize hem. Most likely, it will differ, depending on the window type.

Answer (score 2):

No. It's unlikely, because the contents of those windows must still be stored somewhere.

Comment: ...but the lack of its graphical representation most likely will save some.

Comment: @JacobVlijm It might save video RAM, but I don't think it would save any regular RAM